# How to search a model using multiple fields and to set a priority for them?

Tags: python, django, elasticsearch, django-haystack, solr-boost

I'm using Haystack for searching users in database. I want to check the name of the user, city and state (+abbr of state).

I've done autocomplete using **ElasticSearchEdgeNgramField**.

```
# search_indexes.py

class SwimmerIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
    text = indexes.CharField(document=True, use_template=True)
    name = indexes.CharField(model_attr='get_display_name')
    name_auto = ElasticSearchEdgeNgramField(use_template=True, template_name='search/indexes/sdif/swimmer_text.txt', index_analyzer="edgengram_analyzer", search_analyzer="standard_analyzer")

# swimmer_text.txt

{{ object.get_full_nickname }}
{{ object.state }} {{ object.get_state_display }}
{{ object.city }}
```

And the search.

`sqs = sqs.autocomplete(name_auto=request.GET.get('q', ''))`

I have 2 users in database:

1. Jack Hunt, Oklahoma, OK
2. Jack Smith, Huntsville, AL

When I search for "Jack Hunt" I'm getting:

1. Jack Smith, Huntsville, AL
2. Jack Hunt, Oklahoma, OK

The reason is the city. So I'm searching for the way to boost user if name matches.

I've found one solution.

```
nickname = indexes.CharField(model_attr='get_full_nickname', boost=1.125)
state = indexes.CharField(model_attr='state', boost=1.0)
state_display_name = indexes.CharField(model_attr='get_state_display', boost=1.0)
city = indexes.CharField(model_attr='city', boost=1.0)
```

Following the example from https://django-haystack.readthedocs.io/en/master/boost.html

```
sqs = sqs.filter(SQ(name=AutoQuery(q)) | SQ(state=AutoQuery(q)) | SQ(state_display_name=AutoQuery(q)) | SQ(city=AutoQuery(q)))
```

But after searching for "Jack Hunt" I haven't got Jack Smith from Huntsville. Since his name is not like "Jack Hunt" and his city is not like "Jack Hunt". I know I can search for each word. But it's not very "elastic".

What can I do to make autocomplete on 4 fields and to give more weight for one of them?